# Reduce repeated method calls and change events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below is code for a file I have inherited, which has a lot of manual repetitive code:

```
toggleSizeField: function(action, element) {
  var el = element.find('.size_custom').closest('.form-item');
  this.toggle(action, el);
},
toggleHexField: function(action, element) {
  var el = element.find('.color_custom').closest('.form-item');
  this.toggle(action, el);
},


toggleCustomSize: function(val, element) {
  if (val === 'custom_size') {
    this.toggleSizeField('show', element);
    return;
  }
  if (val === 'default') {
    this.toggleSizeField('hide', element);
    return;
  } else {
  this.toggleSizeField('hide', element);
  }
},
toggleCustomHex: function(val, element) {
  if (val === 'custom') {
    this.toggleHexField('show', element);
    return;
  }
  if (val === 'dark' || val === 'light') {
    this.toggleHexField('hide', element);
    return;
  } else {
    this.toggleHexField('hide', element);
  }
},


$('fieldset.section').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $(this);
  var $radios_1 = $wrapper.find('input.size:radio');
  var $radios_2 = $wrapper.find('input.color:radio');

  var initialVal_1 = $radios_1.filter(':checked').val();
  var initialVal_2 = $radios_2.filter(':checked').val();

  self.toggleCustomSize(initialVal_1, $wrapper);
  self.toggleCustomHex(initialVal_2, $wrapper);

  $radios_1.click(function() {
    self.toggleCustomSize($(this).val(), $wrapper);
  });
  $radios_2.click(function() {
    self.toggleCustomHex($(this).val(), $wrapper);
  });
});
```

Aplogies for the length of it but it's the repeated code I'm concerned with. How can I optimise it? Can I create a loop for these methods? I'm not sure how to pass each custom method in a loop/call it in the `each()` function.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Code optimization? [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @AmmoPT Since it's pseudo-code, he's out of luck on Code Review. [They won't take it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast OP calls it pseudo-code. Looks like functional jQuery code from a project to me.

Comment: @AmmoPT that's correct, it's code I've inherited from a project. I've edited the description. I've made minor changes to the code above and reduced the repeated instances down to two apiece per section.